# Grouping by date and people

Tags: mysql

I am developing a database in php/mysql.

I have a table ‘matterjuncactions’ which contains the fields
actiondate
howlong
staffid

When a member of staff records an action it is entered into the table with the field howlong recording time as a decimal.

A member of staff could record any number of actions in a day. (There are currently 12 staff members)

What I would like to do is have a page showing a table with dates down the left hand side and staff ids across the top with each cell containing the sum of the time spent for that day. (i.e. sum of’howlong’)

So something like:

```
Date       | Staffid 1 | Staff id2 |
6th August | 3.5 | 2.7 |
5th August | 5.7 | 4.6 |
```

etc

I can get the totals for a single staff member using:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(matterjuncactions.actiondate,'%W-%D') AS fDt
     , SUM(howlong) AS tottime 
  FROM matterjuncactions  
 WHERE staffid=1 
 GROUP  
    BY matterjuncactions.actiondate 
 ORDER 
    BY matterjuncactions.actiondate DESC
```

I can’t work out how to get this to display all of the data for all of the staffids.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(matterjuncactions.actiondate,'%W-%D') AS fDt, 
( select SUM(howlong) from matterjuncactions   AS tottime1 where staffid=1) as total1,
( select SUM(howlong) from matterjuncactions   AS tottime2 where staffid=2) as total2  
FROM matterjuncactions  
GROUP  
BY matterjuncactions.actiondate 
ORDER 
BY matterjuncactions.actiondate DESC
```

Hope it helps :)